# How to change the sorting in a cursor

Tags: android, cursor

I am currently working with a Cursor to list all images on the SD card in my Android app. However, I would like the cursor to sort the images after when the images have been created, which is currently not the case.

Does anyone know what I should do?

Thanks!

```
public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths() {
    Uri uri;
    ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
    String PathOfImage = null;
    uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

    cursor = Touch.getTouchContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    column_index_folder_name = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);


    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        PathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        //listOfAllImages.add(PathOfImage);


        filePaths.add(PathOfImage);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Added the selection in the query:

   ```
   cursor = Touch.getTouchContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
   ```
2. Changed the way the cursor adds the files:

   ```
   for (cursor.moveToLast(); !cursor.isBeforeFirst(); cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
       PathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

       filePaths.add(PathOfImage);
   }
   ```